# Load view from NIB file from several different UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios, nsbundle

I have been loading view from Nib files successfully using the approach found on this [site](http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/2009/05/11/load-view-from-nib-improvement/)

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourNibName" owner:self options:nil];
```

The problem is that, because we have to set the File Owner, this nib file becomes "attached" to this view controller. This view is subclass of `UITableViewCell` and I wanted to load this nib file from several different vc's.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll present two options:

- Create a class NibLoader with a single `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet id mainObject;` and a method called `loadNibNamed:bundle:`). Then, do `MyView * v = [[NibLoader loadNibNamed:"MyView" bundle:nil] mainObject];`. (A GCC 4.0 property access bug meant that [...].mainObject would call [...] twice; it's been fixed in 4.2.)
- Create `@protocol MyNibOwner` which has `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyView * myView;`, and change the file's owner class to `id<MyNibLoader>` or `NSObject<MyNibLoader>`.

Comment: or `UIViewController<MyNibLoader>`, but that stops views from loading your nib as a subview in init.

Comment: The second solution sounds perfect, but IB does not accept the protocol after id. Setting it to id and keeping the "broken" reference worked but I suppose its not very safe.

Comment: That's odd, since  `IBOutlet id<FooDelegate> delegate` works perfectly fine (but perhaps it just ignores the protocol in that case; it wouldn't surprise me). You could add a dummy `@interface MyNibOwnerHack:NSObject<MyNibOwner>` for InterfaceBuilder's benefit.

Comment: shameless plug: I have just posted a nice addition to this method that proved very helpful to me on  http://loudcoding.com/posts/add-a-category-to-a-custom-uitableviewcell-when-loading-from-a-nib-file/

Comment: @PauloCasaretto: You probably don't want to do `[self viewWithTag:0]`, since IIRC 0 is the default tag. You also need to be *slightly* careful when reusing tag IDs.

Answer (score 2):

A nib is just a *template*, you can load it over and over again.

If using iOS4, you might want do look at UINib which gives improved performance for repeated nib loading.

Answer (score -1):

Pedantically, a nib should probably have a single controller.  What I would probably do is create a new `UIViewController` subclass that controls the stuff in this nib of yours, and then whenever you want the stuff in the nib, create one of these view controllers and ask *it* for the stuff, instead of loading the nib directly.

Comment: Ugh, no. Embedding view controllers in view controllers is icky, and if you just want the view, you need to do `UIView * v = [[vc.view retain] autorelease]; vc.view = nil; return v;`  or things would behave strangely (I forgot what the bug is or which OS version).